# Get value of setFieldValue immediately

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have two functions, A and B, the first of which updates a formik field using `setFieldValue("Field1", "New Value");` and the second one accesses the updated value via `formikProps.values.Field1`.

Both the functions are run one after another. However, when function `B` tries to access the field it doesn't get the updated value set in `A`. I've read that this is because `setFieldValue` uses setState internally and is async, so the updated value is not available immediately.

I've come across this on Formik github https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529

But all the solutions involve submitting the form, which I want to avoid doing since I only want to update on a specific field changing. Any solution is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but can you use componentDidUpdate or getSnapshotBeforeUpdate to capture the new values once Formik has updated the state?  They should be triggered if the state is changed.

Comment: Im on typescript where props are strongly typed. I can't have access to formik props in useEffect (I'm using a functional component).

Comment: Please show use some more code or create a basic app demonstrating your use case on codesandbox or jsfiddle. This will enable us to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (trick) is to move the 2nd function into an "useEffects" hook which observes any changes on the "Field1" of the Formik values.

```
const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

function functionA() {
    setFieldValue("Field1", "new value");
}

function functionB() {
    const newValue = values.Field1;
    alert(newValue);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fuctionB();
}, [values.Field1]);
```